# Textbox TextChange event only firing if user hits space button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I only have one textbox on the page. For this textbox I have a textbox `text change` event in the code behind. Since this is the only element on the page, it's only firing after user enters input and user hits space button. Is there a hack I could use to make textbook tex changed event happen once it looses focus instead of user hitting space button?

```
<asp:Textbox Id="txtInputID" runat="server" TextChanged="ReadWriteTB_TextChanged" />

private void ReadWriteTB_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Update - I use jquery auto complete for this textbox. Not sure if that is causing user to hit space button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6595702/75500):

```
private void ReadWriteTB_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  txtInputID.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript:this.value=this.value;")
  txtInputID.Focus()
}

<script type="text/javascript">
   var MIN_TEXTLENGTH = 3;

   function forcePostback(ctrl) {
     if (ctrl != null && ctrl.value && ctrl.value.length >= MIN_TEXTLENGTH) {
         __doPostBack(ctrl.id, '');
     }
   }
</script>

...    

<asp:TextBox ID="txtInputID" OnKeyUp="forcePostback(this);" AutoPostBack="true" 
  OnTextChanged="ReadWriteTB_TextChanged" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I need to do a post back /form submit because based on text box value I get data from database and bind it to the repeater on the page. So, I'm not sure if this solution best fits my problem.

Comment: ASP.NET default behavior is that it triggers the server side's `TextChanged` event when the element loses focus. So what's happening in your page? I'm not clear with your question.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not triggering an event when textbook is losing focus. Two possible reasons could be that it's the only element on the page before the post back and I use jQuery auto complete function for the textbox.

Comment: after the post back there is a repeater on the page.